# How to find one or more number in a particular string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to find one or more numbers in a particular string set.
My strings must be of this type:

1. first comes `int` or `uint`.I need to know if it was with `u` or without.
2. second always comes an `integer` number
3. the rest is optional:
   a. there might come "p" or "d"
   b. if there was "p" or "d" then there will come a second number.

examples:

```
"uint16","int32","uint12p2","int32p1","int14d100","uint13d1000"
```

I need to extract all numbers (one or two) and a `boolean` saying if there was u as a first charachter or not.

I'm trying to do this with `regexp`. I've never used it before.

Is there a good reference to learn about rregex?

Thanks.

Comment: MSDN has [alphabet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) and [usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Your best reference to Regex would probably be [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html):

From what I understand you want to get the numbers from a string and determine if those numbers are `uint` or `int`, see this Pseudo code:

```
private void f(string str)
{
    // True if the string contains 'u'
    bool u = false;
    string numbersout:
    string numbers = "1234567890";
    if (str[0] == 'u') bool = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length(); j++)
            if (str[i] == numbers[j]) numbersout += str[i];
}
```

This should work. It checks each number in the string for a number and then adds it to the another string. The bool "u" also sets as true if it's a uint.